# C# HtmlAgilityPack adding tbody

Tags: c#, html, xpath, html-agility-pack

The C# HtmlAgilityPack, adds tbody element after LoadHtml function, into DOM tree in tables even if it doesn't exists in original HTML document. How can I disable this?

My algorithm creates some XPATH expressions, by traversing the dom tree and that non existing tbody element inside original document makes the SelectNodes not find desired items. Took me a lot of time to figure this out :|

Is it possible to make SelectNodes also consider nodes added by HtmlAgilityPack?

Example:

```
<table>
    <tr><td>data</td></tr>
</table>
```

My application would produce this XPATH to extract 'data':
//table/**tbody**/tr/td

The tbody tag in expression was added because its in DOM tree after parsing the html code by HtmlAgilityPack because HtmlAgilityPack added it even if it doesnt exist.
Because of that

```
doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table/tbody/tr/td");
```

would fail.

In other words the tr element (HtmlElement) parent TagName is equal to 'TBODY' not 'TABLE'. Also I'm parsing many different web sites so this is one situation.

SelectNodes is searching in original HTML code, not by DOM tree it has after HtmlDocument.LoadHtml, or it doesn't consider 'virtual' elements added by it.

Comment: I think you just need to change `tr/d` to `tr/td`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use the full hierarchy.

Just use the following if all you want are the `td`s:

```
doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table//td");
```

or just ignore the `tbody` node and get all the hierarchy you care about:

```
doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table//tr/td");
```

Comment: This is just workaround, the algorithm has to deal with many other situations when creating xpath expression and it doesn't suit my needs.
Currently I'm just removing tbody tag from expression but it's also bad idea to do, because when I'm parsing other websites, some sites really have that tbody tag. Also, maybe HtmlAgilityPack adds other elements like tbody to DOM tree even if they dont exist.

Comment: This is not a workaround. It's the way XPath works. Check here: http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#node-tests. `//table` selects all `table` elements descendants from the root node and `//td` selects all `td` elements descendants for the `table` element children of the context node.

Comment: I mean your XPath code is ok, but it is workaround in my situation.
One site has tbody one not, and who knows what other elements HtmlAgilityPack will add on other websites (I have to parse unknown websites to me).